# GitExtensions ignoring .gitignore

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am trying to use git as my VCS for a small project. (Using 2 PCs, both windows)

As I don't like bash I am using gitExtensions, but somehow my .gitignore seems to get ignored by it. 
This is what my .gitignore looks like:

```
nbproject/private/
build/
nbbuild/
dist/
nbdist/
nbactions.xml
nb-configuration.xml
build.xml
```

Now, my folder-structure looks somewhat like this:

```
E:.
├───lib
│   └───<libary stuff>
└───trunk
    ├───build
    │   ├───empty
    │   ├───generated-sources
    │   └───web
    ├───dist
    ├───nbproject
    │   └───private
    ├───src
    │   ├───conf
    │   └───java
    └───web
```

Unfortunately it still includes the whole build folder, and every time I build it i get various new edited files in e.g. the build/generated-sources/ or the dist/, or build/web/

I'm quite new to using .gitignore, so please bear with my low knowledge about it.

Thanks and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The files that you're trying to ignore may already be under version control. If that's the case, you need to remove them from version control, then make a commit. After that, what's listed in `.gitignore` should be properly ignored.

To figure out how to remove files in Git Extensions (v4.0), have a look at the [online documentation](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/release-4.0/commit.html#commit-changes). Besides, KindDragon mentions, in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677015/gitextensions-ignoring-gitignore/25691017#comment40188467_25691017), a feature recently added, called "Show ignored files", which you might find useful.

Comment: Latest manual available here http://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.48/commit.html#commit-changes . New GitExtensions support "show ignored files" in Commit window.

Comment: Links to git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io, both in the answer and the first comment, are broken.

Comment: @Daniel Fixed in the answer, at least.